# python call to c dll passing to wchar**

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I need to change some python code to call into a c api that looks like this:

int start_our_service(WCHAR* extra, int numargs, WCHAR** args);

I have this:

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(__DLL_PATH)
dll.restype = ctypes.c_int32
dll.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int, POINTER(POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))]
data = (ctypes.c_char_p)("-t:9".encode())
ptr = POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)(data)
dll.start_service("TEST", 2, ctypes.byref(ptr))
```

All the args get through ok except the last, the WCHAR**. I'm obviously missing something but can't see it, any ideas?

python 3/windows

TIA

Comment: `POINTER(POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))` looks like it should represent pointer to pointer to `char *` (i.e. `char ***`), not `WCHAR **`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things by trying to declare the function arguments (which, by the way, you are assigning to the dll instead of the function). The simplest amount of code I can come up with that does what you seem to intend to do is:

```
argvector = ctypes.c_char_p * 2
args = argvector(b"-t=9", b"--verbose")
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(__DLL_PATH)
dll.start_service("TEST", 2, args)
```

I.e. Create an array of pointers type, instantiate it and pass it.

I am also passing two arguments where you seem to be passing only one.

Comment: Define the prototype as `dll.start_service.argtypes = (ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_wchar_p))`. The default `restype` is `c_int`, so don't bother with that. Change your array type to `argvector = ctypes.c_wchar_p * 2`, and instantiate it as `args = argvector("-t=9", "--verbose")`.

Comment: The argtypes attribute is optional and belongs in the function if you want it. Putting it on the dll as the OP does has no effect other than perhaps leading you to think your arguments will be checked when they won't.